# Remove surrounding method in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to remove the surrounding method from a statement with a shortcut ?

I want to go from

```
foo(bar(x))
```

to

```
bar(x)
```

as fast and easy as possible.

Kind of the inverse "surround with" functionality. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> is a nice way to select the inner part of the brackets, but how can I keep only this inner part and remove the outer method ?

It should also be possible to go from

```
foobar(foo(bar(x)))
```

to

```
foobar(bar(x))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution i have found so far is by using macros.

If you dont know how to record macros: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-macros-in-the-editor.html

- Step 1: Record this macro:

  - <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>
  - <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>
  - <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>
  - <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
- Step 2: Assign a shortcut to the macro (also discribed in the link above)

If you edit your macro it should look like this:

[image]

---

After these steps you can use this macro pretty comfortably:

- Just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> until you have selected, what you want to keep.
- Then hit your newly assigned shortcut and it will behave just as requested.

Comment: Is there a SaveClipboard and RestoreClipboard action? That would make the macro side-effect free.